# Select XML nodes by attribute in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing

Trying to parse some XML (over which I have no control!)

In C# I would do something like:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name[@type='M']");
```

Can this be done in AS3?

Answer (score 27):

short answer, yes:

```
var xnList:XMLList = xml.Names.Name.(@type == "M");
```

longer version:

```
var xml:XML = <Root>
        <Names>
            <Name type="M" value="John Doe" />
            <Name type="F" value="Jane Doe" />
            <Name type="M" value="John Hancock" />
        </Names>
        <Other />
      </Root>
     
var xnList:XMLList = xml.Names.Name.(@type == "M");

//test
for each (var xnNode:XML in xnList) trace(xnNode.toXMLString())
```

There's a pretty good [E4X tutorial on the Yahoo Developer Network](http://web.archive.org/web/20101204102103/https://developer.yahoo.com/flash/articles/e4x-beginner-to-advanced.html).

HTH