# What vector graphics libraries are available in ActionScript and/or .NET...?

Tags: c#, .net, flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking to build a website that has a flash interface and allows visitors to upload vector art in a number of file formats such as SVG, EPS and AI.

I have two rather large problems...

1) I need to load the original vector art, probably convert it to FLV and display it in my flash application.

2) After the user potentially loads a number of images, adds some text, rotates or transforms some elements, I need to save the resulting composition into a vector art format that I can print.

I'm not much of an AS developer...my experience is mostly in .NET/C# & C++.

I'm looking for a good library or API that provides the functionality I will need to convert different image formats and save the results.

How much of this can be done using Flash / AS...?  How much in C#...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the [libspark svgParser](http://www.libspark.org/browser/as3/SvgParser) before to [generate mxml from an svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612624/a-question-about-parsing-xml-file-in-flex/3612913#3612913) and the similar [fxgParser](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/seven/fxgparser/en) to create animation from a vector file.

The svgParser should come handy, but also have a look at their [svgEditor](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/seven/svgeditor_en).

HTH