# How to compare input text with xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have an search_btn, search_txt (input text), type_txt (dynamic text) and a xml file like this:

```
<ArrayOfWord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <word name="hello " Type="noun"  />
  <word name="hi" Type="verb" />
    <word />
</ArrayOfWord>
```

When i enter a text in search_txt i want to compare it with xml, if true then export the type
example: enter "hello" to search_txt,click search_btn,then the type_txt will export "noun"

anyone plz help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223168/select-xml-nodes-by-attribute-in-as3

Answer (score 0):

### XML

First off, your xml is wrong...

In XML you need to have separate opening and closing tags.  Therefore

`<word name="hello " Type="noun"  />`

needs to be changed to

```
<word name="hello " Type="noun"></word>
  ^^Opening tag                   ^^Closing tag
```

Secondly, xml does not ignore whitespace, so `name="hello "` will only work if you type hello and add a space afterwards.  To fix this just remove the extra space.

The corrected XML code should look like:

```
<ArrayOfWord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <word name="hello" Type="noun"></word>
  <word name="hi" Type="verb"></word>
  <word></word><!--Nothing here?-->
</ArrayOfWord>
```

### AS3

Check out the AS3 docs for [xml loading](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6a.html) and [xml filtering](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e60).  It's good to know how to get the information you need from an xml file.

```
//imports
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.net.URLLoader; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//create a new xml object
var myXML:XML = new XML();
//import xml
//make sure you change the xml file-path here to your own
var XML_URL:String = "sample.xml"; 
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
//if the xml loads correctly go to a function
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

//Function that occurs if xml loads
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    //set myXML to the xml data in the file
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
}
//When the button is pressed find the type
search_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,findword);

//function that finds the type
function findword(event:MouseEvent){
        //set search_string to the word to match
    var search_string:String = search_txt.text;
        //set str (string) to the node value "Type" when 
        //the node value "name" is equal to search_string
    var str:String = myXML.word.(@name == search_string ).@Type;
        //put str into the Type text box
    type_txt.text = str;

}
```

Here is a working [version](http://wonderfl.net/c/exAY).

I hope this helps!

Comment: i use the code up there but get this error :(                                                                                                                                                                        
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable name is not defined.
 at dicpage_fla::rong_mc_1/findword()

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the correct names for the text input and output as well as the button.

Comment: Read the doc on XML filtering from the answer.  `myXML.word.@name` refers to the parameter `name` in the node `word`.  By saying `myXML.word.(@name == search_string).@Type` I am referring to the `Type` parameter of the `word` node that has a `name` parameter that matches the `search_string`.  This code works for me as is with added (and named) button and text boxes.  If `@name` isn't working, it is most likely because you have changed your XML file in some way.

Comment: Looking back at this question, I realized that your XML is written incorrectly... something that I automatically fixed without realizing or mentioning it.  That is most likely the problem.  I have made edits to my answer to reflect that.